# Segmentation fault erore in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

when I run the code below,This class is written for registration, will I get a segmentation error?  what's the reason ?  How can I fix it? Where's my code problem? I used c4droid in android please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
// registration class
class registration 
{
public:
string signup ();
string signin ();
private:
string newuser, newpass, 
user, pass;
};
// signup function 
string registration::signup()
{
cout << " sign up :) " << endl;
cout << " please Enter username : ";
cin >> newuser;
cout << " please Enter password : ";
while (cin >> pass)
{
     cout << " registration complete ;) " << endl;
     break;
}
}
// signin function 
string registration::signin()
{
cout << " signin :) " << endl;
cout << " please Enter username : ";
cin >> user;
cout << " please Enter password : ";
cin >> pass;
if (user == newuser && pass == newpass)
    cout << " you logged in ; ";
else
    cout << " wrong username or password, please try again ";
}
// main
int main ()
{
cout << " welcome " << 
endl;
registration sign;
sign.signup();
sign.signin();
}
```

[Erore picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTTqm.jpg)

Comment: This is very much not C#. If you get an error or not is something you have to try. We can not tell you if you will get an error or no error.

Comment: either pick the tag C or C++ or C#, it cannot be the 3 at the same time...

Comment: FYI, The C# language has garbage collection, C and C++ don't.  C and C++ support pointers; the C# language hides pointer usage (discourages the use of them).  C and C++ don't require the .NET or COM objects.  So, which single language are you programming in?

Comment: BTW, the C language doesn't have the scope resolution operator, `::`.  So I guess you are not programming in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is declared as

```
string registration::signin()
```

ie you declared it to return a `string`, but you do not return anything from the method. Same problem with the other method. Not returning something from a function that you declared to return something is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) <sup>1</sup>. In a nutshell this means your code is incorrect, compilers are not required to diagnose that, can produce any output they feel like, and when you run the code anything could happen.

Either return something or declare them with `void` return.

Another problem is that in `signup` you read `pass` and also in `signin` you read `pass` and compare that to `newpass`. I suppose you want to make the two functions read into two different members and then compare them.

<sup>1</sup>: [`main` is an excpetion, because:](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) if control reaches the end of `main` without encountering a `return` statement, the effect is that of executing `return 0;`

Comment: plus a recommendation to _heed warnings_ wouldn't go amiss

Comment: Error was fixed , Thank you very much for your guidance

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings afaik warnings for no return is nothing to rely on. Of course here compilers should warn, but in general I would not count on it

Comment: Another problem now is when I enter my registration information and when I want to log in it tells me that my username and password are incorrect.

Comment: @RezaShakeri did you fix `pass` vs `newpass` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yeah, thank you, I didn't really care, I didn't do anything to change the pass and the newpass to make it work, so much, thank you very much for your guidance.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I've never seen it not happen when it should.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I was doing some research and found out that the reason the warning cannot be an error is not that it cannot be detected reliably (that was my previous understanding), but because there are cases, where you cannot return on all branches (but are still valid, example [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43943#c4)). So well yes, one can rely on that warning.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings reading that comment on the bugreport again, it also mentions cases that cannot be diagnosed, I think they are rare, but they do exists, so I changed my point again: I would not 100% rely on the warning ;)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings fwiw, I asked a question about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60966763/are-there-cases-of-complilers-not-being-able-to-diagnose-missing-return

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yes that is literally the opposite case: getting the warning when you don't want it, because you didn't use a compiler intrinsic to signal that that particular code path is to be deemed unreachable.